# Play Store on emulated device does not act as Play Store on real device

Tags: android, google-play

I have installed the Play Store on an emulated Android 10 device (Genymotion) running on my PC. Why don't some apps appear when I search for them? TikTok and Revolut are examples. These apps appear on my real phone when searching the Play Store.

I'm using the same Google account on each device. Apps like Facebook and Twitter appear in both devices.

Can anybody explain what's going on? Does the Play Store know I'm running on an emulator and filter apps accordingly?

Comment: check the locale of the emulator, is it the same as of  your device

Comment: Both devices use English and since they have the same Google account, the Play Store country is the same. I was able to find Revolut in the Library section of the Play Store and I get an "Your device is not compatible with this app" message.

Comment: i mean by `Locale`, not the language. Locale represents the region of the device present. Like you are in America or Korea or somewhere else, it returns the value for the same.